# How to refer to columns after an inner join on two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT devices.device_id,
   devices.description,
   sensors.sensor_id,
   sensors.description,
   measurements.value,
   measurements.valueDate,
   measurements.created_at
FROM measurements
INNER JOIN sensors
   ON sensors.id = measurements.sensor_id
INNER JOIN devices
   ON devices.id = sensors.device_id
WHERE devices.device_id = '123456'
   AND sensors.sensor_id = '100102'
   AND measurements.created_at < (
      SELECT created_at
      FROM measurements
      ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
      )
   AND measurements.created_at > DATE_ADD((
         SELECT created_at
         FROM measurements
         ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
         ), INTERVAL - 48 DAY)
```

I believe the problem is in the last two lines... I would like to retrieve the last 48 days from the date that refers to the inner join table and not the entire measurements table. 
i do not know how to refer to a column that belong to the result of the join tables. Should I alias the join tables?

The tables are:

```
Devices
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `device_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `country_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',

Sensors
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `device_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `sensor_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `state` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',

Mesurements
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sensor_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `valueDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `value` float(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
```

Comment: You might be able to do it with a subquery (where the subquery will select the first date taking joins into account).

Comment: i think you have to just do a `between now() interval 48 day`

Comment: When you say 48 days, what is your point of reference the current date that it was queried? Additionally, I think more than the structure sample data (if permissible) would be more helpful in providing you an answer.

Comment: my point of reference is the latest date in created_at of the measurements table after is joint. Instead i do from the entire measurements table.

Comment: So the join produces a range of records and then you want to select only the most recent 48 days worth from that?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Yes, exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution :

```
SELECT devices.device_id,
       devices.description,
       sensors.sensor_id,
       sensors.description,
       m.value,
       m.valueDate,
       m.created_at
FROM (
   SELECT max( m.created_at ) max_date,
          max( m.created_at ) - interval 48 day min_date
   FROM measurements m
   INNER JOIN sensors
      ON sensors.id = m.sensor_id
   INNER JOIN devices
      ON devices.id = sensors.device_id
   WHERE devices.device_id = '123456'
      AND sensors.sensor_id = '100102'
) q
JOIN measurements m
ON m.created_at BETWEEN q.min_date AND q.max_date
INNER JOIN sensors
      ON sensors.id = m.sensor_id
INNER JOIN devices
      ON devices.id = sensors.device_id
WHERE devices.device_id = '123456'
      AND sensors.sensor_id = '100102'
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73a5d/3

**Some remarks:**
The query is joining tables using following comparisons:

- ON sensors.id = measurements.sensor_id
- ON devices.id = sensors.device_id

It's worth mentioning that:

- `sensors.id` is of type `int(10)`, while `measurements.sensor_id` is
  of type `varchar(255)`
- `devices.id` is of type `int(10)`, while `sensors.device_id` is of
  type `varchar(255)`

It's probably a sing that the design of table structures is flawed and needs to be redesigned. This affects the performance, since MySql has to continuously perform a casting from strings to numbers (or vice versa).

Comment: it works! and i agree with you that the structure must be redesigned. For remove ambiguites is better:
   `SELECT max( measurements.created_at ) max_date,
          max( measurements.created_at ) - interval 2 MINUTE min_date`

Comment: Thank you for pointing to ambiguites, I corrected the answer and the demo.